# AttributeError: 'TokenClassifierOutput' object has no attribute 'detach'

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition, detach

Could you please assist me in solving the following error: 'TokenClassifierOutput' object has no attribute 'detach' The error persists even when modifying the code like output = model(input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=input_mask,)
logits = output.loss.detach().cpu().numpy()

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-3e5217186317> in <module>
     13         logits = model(input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=input_mask,)
     14 
---> 15     logits = logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
     16     logits = [list(p) for p in np.argmax(logits, axis=2)]
     17 

AttributeError: 'TokenClassifierOutput' object has no attribute 'detach'
```

```
model.eval()

y_true = []
y_pred = []
eval_loss, eval_accuracy = 0, 0
nb_eval_steps, nb_eval_examples = 0, 0

for batch in valid_dataloader:
    batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
    input_ids, input_mask, label_ids = batch

    with torch.no_grad():
        logits = model(input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=input_mask,)

    logits = logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
    logits = [list(p) for p in np.argmax(logits, axis=2)]
    
    label_ids = label_ids.to('cpu').numpy()
    input_mask = input_mask.to('cpu').numpy()
```

Answer (score 0):

In line 13, it seems that the variable `logits` returned by the `model()` function is an instance of a python Class named `TokenClassifierOutput`.
You can add  `print(logits.__dict__)` after line 13 to figure out what inside this instance.
Anyaway, if you run `logits.detach()` method, `logits` should be an instance of the [pytorch.Tensor](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.detach.html#torch.Tensor.detach) object.

Answer (score 0):

logits = logits.logits.detach().cpu().numpy()

It works

Comment: Do you really want to shadow `logits` here?